# How to find the diameter of a parachute that must slow down the probe on Mars at specific speed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, drag

i'm trying to solve this problem while i'm calculating the Chute diameter that is needed...

The Requirements:

-Mass of the probe that must be slowed down by the parachute (m): 2500 kg

-Drag coefficient of the parachute (Cd):1,75

-Mars Standart gravity (g):3,71 m/s`2

-Air density (r):0,010 Kg/m`3 (The reason for this is because the lander will detach from the parachute at about 4 Km above Martian mean so i decided to put the air density at about 4 Km and that's 0,010 Kg/m`3.

-Velocity that i wanted at 4 Km just before i detach the lander from the parachute: 350 Km/h Or 97,2 m/s

-D: Chute Diameter

So i type this equation:

D = sqrt( (8 m g) / (p r Cd v2) )

And i typed this

sqrt( (8 . 2500 . 3,711) / (3,14 . 0,010 . 1,75 . 97,2`2)

=sqrt( 74200 / 519,1 )

=sqrt143

=11,9 Meter

Now guys, do you think that the Equation is correct, or is there any flaw on the equation that makes everything screwed-up? Or whatever the problem is...Please help me solving this problem.

Thank You :)

Comment: Please see the [homework and exercise](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) policy and note that "check my work" type questions are off topic.  I can't quite follow what you've done, but it's worth noticing that $v$ changes as the parachute slows down the probe; which reduces the force.  It has a cumulative effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base on the fact that starting parachute kinetic energy is exhausted for overcoming negative work done by drag force. If I did modelling correctly you need to solve equation :

$$ \frac{mv_s^2}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\rho C_D \pi r^2h \int_{v_l}^{v_s}vdv = \frac{mv_l^2}{2}$$

for $r$ - parachute radius. Here:

- $v_s$ - starting falling speed right before the moment parachute opens
- $v_l$ - parachute flying speed right before lander detaches from it
- $h$ - falling path length
- $m$ - parachute + payload joint mass

But probably this task can be solved simpler, as you did it, by setting-up terminal speed constraint :
$$ \,{\tfrac {1}{2}}\,\rho \,v_{terminal}^{2}\,C_{D}\,\pi r^2 = mg_{planet} $$ and solving for $r$ too.

Comment: We *never* use the phrase "falling" as long as fuel is in the tank. "Flying" is preferred.